# Use malloc to allocate space for multiple elements in a linked list

Tags: c, struct, malloc

I have a struct in C that is similar to this:

```
struct node{
    char* word;
    struct node* next
}
```

and for every element I have to allocate dynamic space with malloc, like this:

```
struct node* new = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
new -> word = (char*)malloc(k*sizeof(char));   //k is an integer variable
```

but to make the program faster I want to use malloc to allocate, a.e., 50 elements at one time and assign the memory to every element. How can I do that?

Comment: Did you try `sizeof(struct node) * 50` ?

Comment: @Ani assuming the OP is managing a linked list, it will cause problems to allocate a continous block of memory (e.g. you cannot free the memory for a node in the middle).

Comment: "but to make the program faster" --> create a test harness to assess the speed of the application.  Chances are this effort to speed things up with `malloc()` is not that useful.  Your time better spent in a larger review of how to speed things up rather than this micro-optimization.

Comment: @Ani, alternatively `sizeof(struct node[50])`

Comment: @wohlstad you can "free" a node in an array by maintaining another linked list of available nodes. When you need a "new" node: in this sequence a) take one from the linked list, if any, or b) take next node from the array, if any, or c) reallocate the array and goto b). If the "links" are array index numbers (or -1) they won't be invalidated by array reallocation. That might not be appropriate here, when the node also contains a pointer to allocated memory, but if `word` is a short string, OP could use a fixed array for it.

Comment: @WeatherVane I agree it is possible, but it's rather complicated. In my comment I meant to answer @Ani that it is not enough to simply `malloc` with `sizeof(struct node) * 50`.

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick :)

1. You request the amount of size for one item, times 50. (r2)
2. The first few bytes are used for the first node structure (r8)
3. Then, in the for-loop, we add the amount of bytes that the node structure is long to the pointer (r20). Let's say the our allocated memory is on position 100 (for example) in memory. That means that we allocated memory position 100 until 1000 (amusing sizeof(node)==16 and k=2). We simply move up the pointer by 16 and get out new pointer 116.
4. Now, this pointer '116', we put on member 'word' as as char* pointer. As this word is k times long we add this to our current pointer as well (15)
5. And so we start over in the loop, until we filled 50 node structures and it's members.

Don't forget you only have to free the first pointer when you want to get rid of this list.

```
void *mem;
mem = malloc((sizeof(struct node) + (k * sizeof(char))) * 50);

node *firstItem;
node *curIitem;
void *curPos;

firstItem = (struct node*) mem;
curIitem = (struct node*) 0;
curPos = mem;


for (unsigned int i=0; i < 50; i++) {
    if (curIitem != (struct node*) 0) {
        curPos = (void*) ((k * sizeof(char)) + (long long)curPos);
        curIitem->next = (struct node*) curPos;
    }

    curIitem = (struct node*) curPos;
    curPos = (void*)  (sizeof(struct node) + (long long) curPos);
    curIitem->word = (char*) curPos;
}
```

EDITED: modified the example (since it included some errors) and added an explanation.

Comment: `curPos = (void*) ((k * sizeof(char)) + (long long)curPos);` only works if pointers converted to integers act like proper pointer addition.  This is not portable, nor necessary.  Consider _careful_ pointer addition instead.

Comment: Okay, so... I admit I have some struggles to understand how your code works. So, I'll ask you a thing: with your code you're assingning space for 50 elements at once. But I can see this as a normal linked list? And how exactly I can put an element in the list?

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica Pointers are always unsigned numbers that point to a certain place in memory. Therefor you can always do additions and subtractions to pointers. You just have to take care that you don't overflow, underflow or go over your allocated memory(1), that the number is treated as unsigned(2) and that you don't use less bits than a pointer can be long (3). That means that in 32-bit systems you have to use an 32-bit integer, while in 64-bit systems you needs at least a 64-bits integer. How did you get the idea that it is not portable?

Comment: @Ritzy33 I modified the example, since I suddenly realized that it included some errors. I also added an explanation to hopefully answer your question. I hope this makes you understand what happens. If not I like to hear from you again.

Comment: After conversion to an integer "you can always do additions and subtractions to pointers." and end up with the expected pointer is simply not true.  It is not an overflow issue.  If you want more, post a question on that.  Further an `n-bit` system more often refers to the processor width, not the memory capacity - which is a separate issue.  I get the idea it is not portable because there is nothing in the C spec that supports your assertion about pointer-->integer--> addition-->pointer and various implementation that do not use a linear pointer to integer model that are C compliant.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica I worked in assembler for years and pointers are just dwords on 32-bit and qwords in 64-bit systems (dword = 32-bit ,and qword = 64-bit unsigned integer). 'processor width'? n-bits points to the amount of bits it can address. How much memory your system can handle depends on more factors  -- true -- and in the past they used tricks like using multiple registers. But in general n-bit points to the maximum amount of bits the processor can handle in general purpose registers, and those are used to access the memory. That means 32-bit registers cannot access more than 4 gb.

Answer (score 0):

Above are some good suggestions.  Fleshing out a proof-of-principle method, following is a snippet of code utilizing the method of defining your node chain as a structure array.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define NODESIZE 50

struct node{
    char* word;
    struct node* next;
} arx[NODESIZE];

void setup_links(struct node arr[], int arr_size)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < arr_size - 1; i++)
    {
        arr[i].next = &arr[i + 1];
        arr[i + 1].next = NULL;
    }
}

void print_chain(struct node * head)
{
    struct node * work;
    int i = 0;
    work = head;

    while (work != NULL)
    {
        printf("Node: %d, Address: %p\n", i, work);
        i++;
        work = work->next;
    }
}

int main()
{
    setup_links(arx, NODESIZE);

    printf("Size of node list is: %ld\n", sizeof(arx));
    printf("Beginning address for node is: %p\n", arx);
    print_chain(arx);

    return 0;
}
```

Here, the "malloc" is implied when allocating enough memory for fifty structures.  The additional functions were added to prove out that the memory was allocated.  Following, is a sample of the terminal output from running this sample.

```
@Una:~/C_Programs/Console/NodeArray/bin/Release$ ./NodeArray 
Size of node list is: 800
Beginning address for node is: 0x55ab69ade040
Node: 0, Address: 0x55ab69ade040
Node: 1, Address: 0x55ab69ade050
Node: 2, Address: 0x55ab69ade060
Node: 3, Address: 0x55ab69ade070
Node: 4, Address: 0x55ab69ade080
Node: 5, Address: 0x55ab69ade090
Node: 6, Address: 0x55ab69ade0a0
```

As noted, this is just one of the ways you might accomplish the one-off allocation of memory for multiple nodes structures.  You might try out others to see if performance is better.  Give that a try.

Comment: Curious, why use `"%ld"` (which matches `long`) with `sizeof(arx)` (which matches `"%zu"`)?

Comment: Aside: `arr[i + 1].next = NULL;` is execute many times.  `if (arr_size > 0) arr[arr_size].next = NULL;` only needed once after the loop.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of 2 allocations, consider C's [Flexible array member](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flexible_array_member).

```
  struct node {
    struct node *next;
    char word[];  // Move to end
  };

  size_t k = strlen("123") + 1;
  struct node *new = malloc(sizeof *new + sizeof new->word[0] * k);
  if (new) {
    new->next = NULL;
    strcpy(new->word, "123");
  }
```

Not quite the 1 allocation instead of 50, but at least 1 allocation
instead of 2 and is more C idiomatic.

Comment: I tried it but unfortunately this didn't reduce the execution time of the program. Still a useful thing, thank you

Comment: If you really want a reduced the execution time, post an equivalent test harness of the program and ask for a time reduction.  I am sure you will get lots of better feedback than this "how to reduce time using an approach I think is good".

Comment: I understand, I think... Just, what is a test harness?

Comment: [test harness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Test_harness).  e.g. `int main() { start = get_time(), do_your_code_n_times(1000); print_elapsed_time(start, 1000); }`.